# In javascript ,Access to global variable whenever its name is same with local variable?

Tags: javascript

```
var a="abc";
function(){
var a="efg";
console.log(a);//I need global variable value "abc" here
}
function();
```

I need the value "abc" in the console. How can I get global variable value?

Comment: First, `function();` will give you error. You are also missing function name here `function(){` Second, you can try `window.a` but this will **not** work if your code is wrapped in function.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get global variable value?

use `window.a`

```js
var a = "abc";

function a1() {
  var a = "efg";
  console.log(window.a); 
}
a1()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example, since you used `var` at global scope, you can access it on the global object, which is accessible via the `window` global on browsers; so `window.a`:

```js
var a="abc";
function example(){
  var a="efg";
  console.log(window.a);//I need global variable value "abc" here
}
example();
```

**However**, if that global were created by using `const`, `let`, or `class` at global scope, e.g.:

```
let a = "abc";
```

...you would not be able to access it at all within that function, because even though globals created via `const`, `let`, or `class` *are* globals, they are not properties of the global object.

Comment: *since you used var* should be *since you used `var` **outside any function***. Also it would be nice if you can also mention that `window.a` will not work if OP's code is wrapped in a function.

Comment: @Rajesh: The premise of the question is that the first `var` creates a global. Thus, it's outside any function.

Comment: Just thought above sentence might mislead readers, hence requested you to add a caveat. I'll leave the comment for any such readers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get global variable value `a`?

By not naming your local variable `a` as well.

```
var a = "abc";
function example(){
    var b = "efg";
    console.log(a); // The global variable with the value "abc"
    console.log(b); // The local variable with the value "efg"
}
example();
```

It's local to your function anyway, so you can rename to it anything you want without impacting other functions. Don't use names that you need to access global variables.